# Xamarin forms : Issues with xamarin popup image

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup Nuget for showing a popup. My doubt is how can I call a popuppage from viewmodel class? I am using the following code in viewmodel.

```
  var page = new Pages.MyPopUpImage();
  await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page);
```

Getting MissingMethodException when running the project.  Also not working in xaml.cs class, getting the same exception there.

```
[0:] Exception:>>System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRendererWithContext' not found.
at Rg.Plugins.Popup.Droid.Impl.PopupPlatformDroid+<AddAsync>d__11.MoveNext () [0x0002c] in C:\projects\rg-plugins-popup\src\Rg.Plugins.Popup.Droid\Impl\PopupPlatformDroid.cs:45 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
at Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigationImpl+<AddAsync>d__11.MoveNext () [0x00039] in C:\projects\rg-plugins-popup\src\Rg.Plugins.Popup\Services\PopupNavigationImpl.cs:111
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.. how can I call a popuppage from viewmodel class?
```

One option is to pass `Navigation` from your `Page` to the `ViewModel`. There are multiple ways how to do it, one quick and dirty way will be to pass it via constructor for example and then it will be easy to open a popup:

```
await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new MyPopUpPage());
```

P.S.: **System.MissingMethodException** can be a cause of missing [initialization](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup#initialization) & might be that [this issue](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/116) is related.

P.S.S: Try to delete bin & obj directories and rebuild + make sure that you have only one version of NuGet package installed.

Comment: Try like your suggestion, but again getting the same exception : MissingmethodException. I edit the question with the complete exception details

Comment: Are you sure you tried the exact thing I proposed => await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new MyPopUpPage()); instead of await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page);

Comment: I try like this await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new Pages.MyPopUpPage());

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the same. Depends on the navigation stack of your project.

Comment: Also tried await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new Pages.MyPopUpPage());
Got navigation does not exist in the current context error

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: In android mainactivity I added the code for initialization:
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);

Comment: Updated my answer again, if it will not help I would suggest to report an issue directly on https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/

Comment: Deleting bin and obj directories and rebuild the solution solves the issue.But the style of button changed in the entire project, I use rounded corner buttons, now all are showing as normal buttton.

Comment: The property of border radius of the button didn't work after deletion of bin and obj folder + rebuild.